# php conditional problem

Tags: php

Goal:
User only selects **one**, **only one** option at a given time for the **denomination**, either some value of Nickels **only**,
some **value of Dimes** **only**, or some **value of Quarters only**.

**Problems:** Currently the code only **defaults to Nickels only**?

**Pre-existing condtion:**
If I select a different denomination, for example, **Quarters only**, I only get the values for Nickels, the same applies for Dimes?

Code Snippet:

```
if($denomination["Nickels"] != NULL)

{
$value = $denomination["Nickels"];
echo $value . " is the value of selected Nickels";
}

else if ($denomination["Dimes"] != NULL)
{
$value = $denomination["Dimes"];
echo $value . " is the value of  selected Dimes";
}

else if ($denomination["Quarters"] != NULL)
{
$value = $denomination["Quarters"];
echo  $value . "is the value of selected Quarters";
}
```

Comment: Dear me you like asking questions about nickels and dimes: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:170622+dime

Comment: Lol indeed yeah ;) I've noticed too ;) +1 for you!

Comment: use if (isset($denomination["Nickels"]) not != NULL

Comment: I believe that the three sets of questions; (a) tagged "php", (b) asked by "Newb", and (c) related to a problem with denominations, are rapidly converging.

Comment: could you post the output from `print_r($denomination)` ?

Comment: Building a vending machine in php, I guess if this was JS it would have been easier; however, it's not that's the learning in php, so I just want to get this working to some extent in php, that's why my questions might seem to converge on dimes, arrays, denominations, etc.

Comment: It's all about the money and user...

Comment: No, just kidding it's all about  learning or trying to learn php.

Comment: That's probably going to do it for now, thank you to all you guys for your support.
I should be able to fix this code with the help you guys have provided and get my php vending machine to work.

If at first you don't succeed, try harder.
Again thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it short:

```
<?php
$value = array_shift(array_filter($denomination));
echo  $value . "is the value of selected Quarters";
```

With this you don't have to put in a if for every new element.

Answer (score 2):

The "elseif" stops processing when the first condition is true (i.e. "Nickels").
Remove the "else"s and leave plain "if"s.

Answer (score 0):

Are you explicitly setting the values in the $denomination array to null?

Have you trying something like...

```
if($denomination["Nickels"])
{
$value = $denomination["Nickels"];
echo $value . " is the value of selected Nickels";
}

else if ($denomination["Dimes"])
{
$value = $denomination["Dimes"];
echo $value . " is the value of  selected Dimes";
}

else if ($denomination["Quarters"])
{
$value = $denomination["Quarters"];
echo  $value . "is the value of selected Quarters";
}
```

Comment: No, but I assure you, I will be in the code cave with all this good stuff experimenting, until I get this baby of the ground, so yes I will by trying your code Chris Gutierrez, and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try not using the elseifs, replace them with ifs

```
if($denomination["Nickels"] != NULL)

{
$value = $denomination["Nickels"];
echo $value . " is the value of selected Nickels";
}

if ($denomination["Dimes"] != NULL)
{
$value = $denomination["Dimes"];
echo $value . " is the value of  selected Dimes";
}

if ($denomination["Quarters"] != NULL)
{
$value = $denomination["Quarters"];
echo  $value . "is the value of selected Quarters";
}
```